# How to scan phtml and embedded javascript files in SonarQube?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner, static-code-analysis, sonarqube-5.0

I did sonarqube analysis on DemoProject.
I am having phtml and embedded files in it.

1. How to scan PHTML files?
2. PHTML files contains some Javascript code.
   Can we scan this javascript code?
3. Can anyone suggest a solution for this?
4. Is there any plugins available for the same?

Note:- I already installed javascript plugin and web plugin

Answer (score 2):

For Scanning phtml files, Please install PHP plugin, PHP plugin within SonarQube supports scanning of phtml files.

Please find below the screenshot for the same.

[image: This screeenshot shows default extension supported by SonarQube(PHP) Plugin]

Please go to settings->PHP where you can see this settings.

if you want to specify the same in project properties file, you have to add following the key

```
sonar.php.file.suffixes= file extensions
```

Answering you other question of embedded code analysis. This is not supported by SonarQube. It identifies the file extension and then scan for the same.

Answer (score 0):

In Sonar no dedicated PHTML plugin but WEB plugin for html and PHP plugins are used to analyse these files.
install PHP and WEB plugin and try sonar analysis again.